# youtube api C# video full meta data

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to get youtube video information for each video in my youtube playlist. That way I can hook my PowerBI dashbaords and other email tool to a SQL database with all my youtube video meta data in it. I have a method that will grab all of the Snippet video information. But it fails when grabbing the other parts.This link clearly shows that content details is a valid operation but the APIgives me a 400 back. I have to be really close. Any ideas?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters

```
    public YouTubeVideo GetVideoInfo(string id)
    {
        var videoRequest = ytservice.Videos.List("snippet");
        var contentRequest = ytservice.Videos.List("contentdetials");
        var itemRequest = ytservice.Videos.List("items");
        var statsRequest = ytservice.Videos.List("Statistics");
        videoRequest.Id = id;
        contentRequest.Id = id;
        itemRequest.Id = id;
        statsRequest.Id = id;
        var response = videoRequest.Execute();
        var contentResponse = contentRequest.Execute();
        var itemResponse = itemRequest.Execute();
        var statsResponse = statsRequest.Execute();
        var video = new YouTubeVideo();
        if (response.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            video.id = videoRequest.Id;
            video.caption = contentResponse.Items[0].ContentDetails.Caption;
            video.title = response.Items[0].Snippet.Title;
            video.description = response.Items[0].Snippet.Description;
            video.publishDate = response.Items[0].Snippet.PublishedAt.Value;
            video.ageGate = itemResponse.Items[0].AgeGating.Restricted;
            video.viewCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.ViewCount;
            video.likeCount = statsResponse.Items[0].Statistics.LikeCount;
            video.dislikeCount = statsResponse.Items[0].Statistics.DislikeCount;
            video.favoriteCount = statsResponse.Items[0].Statistics.FavoriteCount;
            video.commentCount = statsResponse.Items[0].Statistics.CommentCount;
        }
        else
        {
            //Video not found
        }
        return video;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out i could make all of the calls in the same string just seperated by commas :)

```
    public YouTubeVideo GetVideoInfo(string id)
    {
        var videoRequest = ytservice.Videos.List("snippet, contentDetails, statistics");
        videoRequest.Id = id;
        var response = videoRequest.Execute();
        var video = new YouTubeVideo();
        if (response.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            video.id = videoRequest.Id;
            video.caption = response.Items[0].ContentDetails.Caption;
            video.title = response.Items[0].Snippet.Title;
            video.description = response.Items[0].Snippet.Description;
            video.publishDate = response.Items[0].Snippet.PublishedAt.Value;
            //video.ageGate = (response.Items[0].AgeGating.Restricted = null) ? null : response.Items[0].AgeGating.Restricted;
            video.viewCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.ViewCount;
            video.likeCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.LikeCount;
            video.dislikeCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.DislikeCount;
            video.favoriteCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.FavoriteCount;
            video.commentCount = response.Items[0].Statistics.CommentCount;
        }
        else
        {
            //Video not found
        }
        return video;
    }
```